# How to update users custom attribute from my azure ad b2c using python

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, fastapi

I need to update the user custom attribute by using python or fastapi,will anyone help me with the code or any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Microsoft Graph REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http